# jQuery - How do I make the menu fadeout when the user clicks anywhere else in the document besides the menu itself?

Tags: jquery, click, menuitem, fadeout

I have a link that functions similar to a drop down menu in that it fades in a list of links below it when clicked. Currently, the list fades back out when the link is clicked again, but I'd like for it to also fade out if the user clicks elsewhere on the page. I'm not sure how to add the **$(document).click(function()...** that handles this, or if this is even the right approach. Here is my code:

```
$('#show_button').click( function(){
    if(!$('#list').is(':visible')){
        var pos = $('#show_button').offset();
        $('#list').css({'left':pos.left - 11, 'top': pos.top+14}).fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        $('#list').fadeOut();
    }   
});
```

I am trying to add something like this to make the list fade out when the user clicks anywhere else in the page:

```
if($('#list').is(':visible')){
    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#list').fadeOut();
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance - I would appreciate any help on this one :)

Comment: haha... It took me a while to sort out, but I actually ended using a combination of PlagueEditor, hunter, hornairs, Kyle, and Sebastian Moser's answers along with some cross browser compatibility code.

Comment: Here's what I came up with:
 $('#show_button').click( function(){
  if(!$('#list').is(':visible')){
   var pos = $('#show_button').offset();
   $('#list').css({'left':pos.left - 11, 'top': pos.top+14}).fadeIn();
  }

  else{
   $('#list').fadeOut();
  }

        $('body').click(function(e){
                e = e || window.event;
                target = e.target || e.srcElement;
                if (target.id != 'show_button'){
                    $("#list:visible").fadeOut();
                }
        });
 });

Comment: LOL oh wow - that didn't turn out well... I'll answer my own question... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the element that the event is targeting and see if the id is equal to `list`. If it is not, then `fadeOut()` list

```
$(document).click( function(e){
    if (e.target.id != "list") $("#list").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Added this check to my solution - THANKS! - totally a vital piece of code for what I'm trying to do ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now but you're logic seems ok; however, the if statement should be inside the click handler, otherwise it wouldn't fire.

```
    $(document).click(function() {
        if($('#list').is(':visible')){
             $('#list').fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

Comment: this will fadeOut() `list` if you click `list`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the click event to the document you could try binding it to the body element.

```
$('body').click(function (event){
    //code here you may have to return false to stop the
    //click event from bubbling up or use event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I use this suggestion in combination with others listed here - thanks :) Now I need to remove the event or return false when the list is no longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta flip the order of your if statement. When its on the outside of the click handler, like you have put above, it will only be checked once, when the script is first executed. Instead, you want it to check if `#list` is visible each time somewhere is clicked. So, put it inside the handler.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if($('#list').is(':visible')){
        $('#list').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

You could even get fancy and move the check into the selector, which I think might be a bit faster.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#list:visible').fadeOut();
});
```

As far as I know, `$(document).click()` is a perfectly valid strategy to use. You should put the event handler in a script that is loaded after jQuery, but it doesn't really matter where, and it doesn't really matter if the DOM is ready yet I don't think.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this will fadeOut() `list` if you click `list`

Comment: Burn, you are right. Gotta add the check from your answer. Will the target.id of the event object always be "list" no matter what element the user clicks inside the list?

Comment: target.id will only equal "list" if you clicked on "list"

Comment: Moved the if statement inside of the click handler. I used your suggestion combined with others here - Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the one-function in jQuery. It allows you to listen for an event only once, after which the event handler will be dismissed again. (This saves memory, which is generally a good thing, but especially important in JavaScript-heavy web sites.)

```
$(document).one('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != "list") {
    $('#list:visible').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: this will fadeOut() `list` if you click `list`

Comment: Sorry bro, but there's still a difference --> I use the one function so that you don't waste browser resources for an event handler that's not necessary very often. ;)

Comment: Oh: And I can't seem to comment yet on other people's answers, so I had no way to tell you about that. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I definitely need to save memory, but I think for this page, the user will need the option of clicking more than once. There are AJAX accordion elements on the page that they will probably peruse before clicking the link to leave the page. Any suggestions on how I should remove the event once the list is gone?

Answer (score 0):

OK... Here's what I have so far. It's a combination of several solutions above plus some cross browser code. The only thing I have to do now is remove the the **$('body').click(function(e){...** once the list is no longer visible. OR add it only when the list is visible. Any suggestions?

BTW... Thanks for your help PlagueEditor, hunter, hornairs, Kyle, and Sebastian Moser - I can't promote anyone's answers yet because I'm new :(

```
$('#show_button').click( function(){
    if(!$('#list').is(':visible')){
        var pos = $('#show_button').offset();
        $('#list').css({'left':pos.left - 11, 'top': pos.top+14}).fadeIn();
    }

    else{
        $('#list').fadeOut();
    }

    $('body').click(function(e){
            e = e || window.event;
            target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            if (target.id != 'show_button'){
                $("#list:visible").fadeOut();
            }
    });
});
```